# Regularilty of Commutative Spectral Triples

Tags: riemannian-geometry, oa.operator-algebras, sp.spectral-theory, noncommutative-geometry, spin-geometry

In Connes' approach to non-commutative geometry, the notion of a [spectral triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_triple) is said to generalize compact Riemannian manifolds to the non-commutative setting. Motivating classical examples include the operator $d + d^*$ on Riemannian manifold, where $d$ is the exterior derivative and $d^*$ is its adjoint with respect to the metric. Another example is the operator $\overline{\partial} + \overline{\partial}^*$ on a compact Hermitian manifold.

According to Wikipedia, a spectral triple is **regular** if

> Let $\delta(T)$ denote the commutator of $|D|$ with an operator $T$ on $H$. A spectral triple is said to be **regular** when the elements in $A$ and the operators of the form $[a, D]$ for $a \in A$ are in the domain of the iterates $\delta^n$ of $\delta$.

Is it easy to see that the two commutative examples given above are regular?